# Making an icon out of synaptic

Tags: synaptic

I'm a Ubuntu newbie and only using Ubuntu 16.04 (kind of scared to try to move to 18.04 or 20.04). So, I know that I'm behind but 16.04 is fine for my current purposes.

From googling for how to install some software, I recently learned about the synaptic package manager. I was able to install it and it's really been great in that it saves me problems as far as dealing with dependencies when installing new software. My only question is if it's possible to make an icon out of it that sits in the column on the left side with the other icons ? Right now, I type "synaptic" at the command line but I'm thinking that there must be a way to do that. A reference to a link is fine. I couldn't find one.

Comment: 16.04 is still supported, but won't be past April, so don't wait too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synaptic already has an icon which looks like a cardboard carton with a green arrow in the lower right corner. Search for Synaptic icon in the Dash and click the Synaptic icon to open it. When Synaptic is open right-click the Synaptic icon in the Launcher and select *Lock to Launcher*. To remove the Synaptic icon from the Launcher right-click the Synaptic icon in the Launcher and select *Unlock from Launcher*.

In Ubuntu 17.10 and later the Launcher is called the Dock and the two options in the context menu for the Synaptic icon in the Launcher are *Add to Favorites* and *Remove from Favorites*.

[image]

Comment: thanks karel. I do see the icon when the app is opened but  I must be hard-headed because when I right click on the icon in the dash, I just get 3 options: synaptic package manager, lock from launcher and quit. maybe I installed it incorrectly ? thanks for through answer and diagram. only I can't work it out given all that information. :).

Comment: karel: I don't know if I mis-read your original email or you changed it but "lock to launcher" worked perfecto-ly. thank you so much.